# Display php mysql data column with group by sum

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I want to generate report in phpmysql in such a way that first detail rows display and in the bottom , sum of that detail row display on the basis of group by statement.

```
Select id, 
       Emp-name,  
       department, 
       salary, 
       sum(salary) as total sum for each dept
from Employee 
group by department

I tried the following  thing
Select id, 
       Emp-name,  
       department, 
       salary, 
       (select sum(salary) from Employee) as total sum for each dept
from Employee 
group by department
```

desired out put :

| Employee Name | Department | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Umar | IT | 50000 |
| ali | IT | 40000 |
| sub total | IT | 90000 |
| waseem | HR | 25000 |
| waqar | HR | 15000 |
| sub total | HR | 40000 |

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Please share data as text not images so it can be easy for us to help you

Comment: Have you tried `GROUP BY department WITH ROLLUP`?

Comment: yes i did but with roll up row, it repeat other column values. whch i dont want

Answer (score 0):

Your query is grouping by department which will give the total per department and the name and salary of the first employee (which is useless to you here).
You would need to do a separate query to get totals per dept, but in this case it's better to just order by dept and then do a subtotal per dept when the dept changes. e.g. (pseudo code)

```
while ($row = fetcharray($result))
{
   if ($row['dept'] != $dept)
   {   if ($dept)
       {   // do subtotal
           $dept_salary = 0;
       }
       $dept = $row['dept'];
   }
   // do employee row
   $dept_salary += $row['salary'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here's what you are looking for:**

```
select emp_name, department, salary from employees
       UNION ALL
       select 'sub-total' emp_name, department department,  sum(salary) salary from employees GROUP BY department;
```

Comment: and for grand total ? i have to add one more union ? will it slow sql querry ?????/

Comment: do you want both grand total and sub-total ?

Comment: yes i needed both. How can i do that ?